# Javascript: Know all the elements under your mouse pointer (multiple z-axis layers)

Tags: javascript

So there's this really cool fiddle which allows you to fetch the element under your pointer:

http://jsfiddle.net/MPTTp/

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX, y = e.clientY,
        elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    alert(elementMouseIsOver);
})
```

I have multiple z-axis layers, and I want to know ALL the elements under my pointer.

Any advice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just look under each element until you reach the html tag. You can hide/show elements or use pointerEvents for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gwy2u/

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY,
        stack = [],
        elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    stack.push(elementMouseIsOver);

    while (elementMouseIsOver.tagName !== 'HTML'){

        elementMouseIsOver.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

        stack.push(elementMouseIsOver);
    }

    /* Now clean it up */
    var i  = 0,
        il = stack.length;

    for (; i < il; i += 1) {
        stack[i].style.pointerEvents = '';
    }

    console.log(stack);
});
```

along with this css style:

```
.pointerEventsNone {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

---

## Update:

Using classList to add/remove a pointer-events propriety is more elegant: as demonstrated [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gwy2u/1/) and below:

```
function elementsAtLocation (x,y){
    var stack= [], el;
    do {
        el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
        stack.push(el);
        el.classList.add('pointerEventsNone');
    }while(el.tagName !== 'HTML');

    // clean up
    for(var i  = 0; i < stack.length; i += 1)
        stack[i].classList.remove('pointerEventsNone');

    return stack;
}
```

**Old browsers:**
Using display:none for older browser, however this will trigger repaint/reflow: http://jsfiddle.net/Gwy2u/2/

Comment: Cool!  Seems `pointerEvents` lets you tell the element to ignore mouse events.  That's awesome :-D

Comment: Yes, you can also use display: none if you want to support older browsers

Comment: FYI, it's a no-go in IE10: http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events . Also note that this implementation won't yield elements that *already* have `pointer-events:none`.

Comment: True, you can feature detect if this is supported and in case just go with display: none. However display: none will trigger reflow/repaint. This is why this fiddle is using pointer-events

Comment: For **Angular** users, you'll need to prefix the css class with `/deep/`, as in : `/deep/ .pointerEventsNone {
    pointer-events: none;
}`

Comment: This may not work: display:"none" triggers a reflow. Say you have a list and the mouse pointer is on the first elem. You will end up having all the list items, of which only 1 was originally under the mouse pointer. I did not test it, but visibility:"hidden" may be a better choice, as it retains the "place of the element. What I don't know, if visibility:"hidden" is see-through for mouse events, or not...

Comment: Just tested: visibility:"hidden" (ff) is not see-through for mouse events.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you can try

```
const elements = document.elementsFromPoint(x, y);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementsFromPoint

Based on the description, elementsFromPoint() method of the DocumentOrShadowRoot interface returns an array of all elements at the specified coordinates (relative to the viewport).

Comment: Yes, this answer shall be on the top! Using 'document.elementsFromPoint()' is native and much more efficient method to get all elements at given coordinates. The problem with using 'document.elementFromPoint()' (singular) is that you need to change style attributes of the stacked elements, and this takes too long.

Answer (score 6):

There is another option

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY,
        stack = [];

    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var len = allElements.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         var elm = allElements[i];
         var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();

         if(y >= rect.top && y <= rect.bottom && x >= rect.left  &&  x <= rect.right){
            stack.push(elm);
                 }
    } 
    console.log(stack);
});
```

example link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Gwy2u/41/

Comment: Pros: Better than modifying the elements.
Cons: Bad if there's lots of elements on a document or node being searched under, as this cycles through all of them.

I definitely like the `.getBoundingClientRect()` use! 